# Get a value from an AT Command

Tags: arduino, command, gsm, at-command

i would like to ask your help for a code i want to make.I am using a gsm sim808 and an arduino uno and i want to get the capacity from the battery attached to gsm and send it to thingspeak.
The AT command is AT+CBC but that returns 3 values something like this : (x,xx,xxxx) which is 1st value 0-2 if battery is charging or not, 2nd value 0-100 is the battery capacity and 3rd value is the milivolt of the battery. So what i want is to get the capacit value and put it into a variable so i can send it to thingspeak. Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Look up the arduino string for functions.

Comment: You have the command, you just need to extract the second value. Check if the returned value is a string (https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/stringobject/) or an array (https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/array/)

Comment: What i get from that command is a single line like that:     +CBC (0,61,3889)  .   Dunno if its a string but i tried to put it in a string and then maybe substring to get the right value?

Comment: If I send `AT+CBC=?` the sim808 answers with `+CBC: (0-2),(1-100),(voltage)`. According to [m2msupport.net](https://m2msupport.net/m2msupport/atcbc-battery-charge/) the first field indicates whether the battery is being charged, the second field the state of charge in percent and the last field the state of charge in volts.